# Is this method of solving equations true?

Tags: systems-of-equations

Is this statement true  , for all numbers
" If A * B * C = X * Y * Z , THEN {X,Y,Z}={A,B,C} " ?
If not , when is this statement true ?
I ask this question as I have came across the solution of a system of equations in a textbook , it concludes with
As (Z-x)(Z-y)(Z-z) = (Z-a)(Z-b)(Z-c) , then (x,y,z) is a permuation on {a,b,c} .
( Z (capital Z) is a a variable in the set of complex numbers, we solve for (x,y,z) )

Comment: The first statement you make is clearly not correct.  $1\times 1\times 8=2\times 2\times 2$.  Of course, a monic polynomial over $\mathbb C$ determines and is determined by its roots.

Comment: It is vitally important to be clear about which quantifiers control which parts of a statement. “For all ... if” is very different from “if for all ... “.

Comment: The first statement is not true, as I'm sure you suspect.  For example, $2\cdot 8\cdot 6 = 3\cdot 4\cdot 8$ but the set $\{2,8,6\}$ is not the same as $\{3,4,8\}$, is it?  However when you introduce the variable $Z$ in the second statement, this provides much stronger information, an equality of *polynomials*, where all the corresponding coefficients have to be equal.  The second statement is valid.

Comment: By [Fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) the statement from the textbook is true. It is not equivalent to the first one, however.